# Jar File running on windows but not showing GUI

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, fxml

I created a javafx program on intelij its working, but when I created a jar File and tried to ran it, it is running because it created a default File like we have programed but it's not showing GUI. Is it possible because our main is in a package? And if so when we tried to move it we have manifest errors, can someone Please help?

Comment: 1. Check if your `JAVA_HOME` version is right (not lower). 2. Check if your javafx library is not 32 bit if you want to run it on 64 bits machine.

Answer (score 3):

To see any errors your app is throwing, use Command Prompt to open the .jar file, like this:

```
java -jar C:\\path\to\your\executable.jar
```

From there, you can see if it throws an error.

Is it working in IntelliJ? And your program works with files? Sounds like it can't find the necessary files, because it's executed in a path different from the IntelliJ's output directory path (which happens to work).

Comment: It says couldnt create JVM a fatal exception has occured. Program will exit

Comment: Can you edit your post by adding the error log? As well as adding the relevant code, if possible.

Comment: This is all that it says...

Comment: And I really don't know where the problem is...

Comment: Is there a way to upload the whole project? So that more experienced people will have a look. Because its my university project and I'm missing my deadline...